# Replace hashtag with link and underscore with space

Tags: c#

I want to replace hashtag with link and replace the underscore in a word that contains hashtag only with a space in C# and use regex.

example :
Futbol Club #Barcelona, commonly known as #Barcelona and familiarly as Barça, is a professional football club based in Barcelona, #Real_Madrid

here i want replace all words that start with # to a link and also replace underscore to space only at words start with hashtag i want use it in one line code below replace words that start with hashtag but i cant replace also underscore .

```
string replacePattern = @"(#)(\w+)";
string replacementString = @"<a href='http://www.xsite.com/search?word=$2'> $2 </a>";

return Regex.Replace(str, replacePattern, replacementString);
```

Comment: Please format your code as real code and the question and not just as plain text.

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Better give an example

Comment: Other than providing an example, what's the problem you're faced with? Why doesn't the linked code snippet work? As of now, we only have a description of your goals and a code snippet that (at a glance) looks usable.